# Recurrence relation $T(n) = T(n-1)+\frac 1n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

How can we solve this recurrence relation
$T(n) = T(n-1)+\frac 1n$

I would like to calculate the time complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: Why don't you to write down $T(n)$ for small $n$ and observe the pattern (use $\sum$)

Comment: When you see the pattern $T(n)-T(n-1)=f(n)$ think telescoping sum.You end up with $T(n)-T(0)=\sum f(n)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "solve" the recurrence relation to get (assuming $T(1) = 1$) something like

$$ T(n) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}$$

This is the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), which is famously very close to $\log_e(n)$.

Comment: This is what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}T(n) &=T(n-1) +\frac{1}{n}\\
&=T(n-2) +\frac{1}{n-1} +\frac{1}{n}\\
&=T(n-3) +\frac{1}{n-2} +\frac{1}{n-1} +\frac{1}{n}\\
&\vdots\\
&=T(1) +\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k}.
\end{align}